# Issue with RVM conflicting with Brew?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, homebrew, rvm

I'm running OSX 10.9.3.

I have installed Brew, Macports, RVM, rbenv, and other tools in the process of learning and following tutorials.

I was not aware that some of these tools do the same thing and I have since done this:

$`brew doctor` I moved `macports` as it suggested and `rm -rf`'d several gems showing warnings, so now the `brew doctor` command runs error free (sort-of, keep reading).

My `bash_profile` looks like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #1

if [ -f ~/.bash_git ]; then #2
  source ~/.bash_git
  export PS1='\033[00;37m\]\W\033[00;36m\]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\033[00m\]: '
fi

alias ll="ls -lahG" #3

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH" #4
```

When I run `rvm -v` I get back `Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/fab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin' is not at first place ...`

It continues to say run `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles` which produces:

> Downloading https://get.rvm.io dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib   Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/curl
>   Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 8.0.0 or
>   later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0 RVM reloaded!

So as you can see that doesn't work... (**Side question--- how can I update curl? I did a brew install curl and it returned 7.37 as latest version**) Anyways, if I remove line `#4` and run `brew doctor` the `rvm` issue goes away but `brew` shows this warning:

> Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin This means that
>   system-provided programs will be used instead of those provided by
>   Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:
>
> ```
> c++
> cpp
> curl
> curl-config
> g++
> gcc
> gcov
> ```
>
> Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin occurs before
>   /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:

**How can I fix this conflict between `rvm` and `brew`?**

Finally if I do `ls -la` in my root I get a ton load of files which I'm guessing may be conflicting... Here is the output:

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 56 fab  staff   1.9K May 24 18:21 .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root          admin   170B Dec 31 21:05 ..
-rw-------   1 fab  staff     3B Jan 17 23:47 .CFUserTextEncoding
-rw-r--r--@  1 fab  staff    21K May 24 18:35 .DS_Store
drwx------  22 fab  staff   748B May 24 18:34 .Trash
-rw-------   1 fab  staff     0B May 22 20:23 .Xauthority
drwxr-xr-x   4 fab  staff   136B Jun 23  2013 .adobe
drwxr-x---   9 fab  staff   306B Feb  8 19:18 .android
-rw-r--r--   1 fab  staff    13K Jan 16 18:38 .bash_git
-rw-------   1 fab  staff    16K May 24 18:42 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--@  1 fab  staff   294B May 24 18:51 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--   1 fab  staff     0B Jan 25 19:57 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x   3 fab  staff   102B Jan  1 00:56 .bundler
drwxr-xr-x   3 fab  staff   102B Sep 15  2013 .cache
drwxr-xr-x   3 fab  staff   102B May 22 13:58 .config
drwx------   3 fab  staff   102B Jun 21  2013 .cups
drwxr-xr-x   3 fab  staff   102B Jan 23 12:43 .distlib
drwx------  20 fab  staff   680B May 24 17:55 .dropbox
drwx------   4 fab  staff   136B Apr 25 08:47 .dropbox-master
drwx------   7 fab  staff   238B Oct  7  2013 .filezilla
drwxr-xr-x   4 fab  staff   136B May 11 15:50 .fontconfig
drwxr-xr-x   4 fab  staff   136B Jan  1 00:58 .gem
-rw-r--r--   1 fab  staff    84B Feb  5 18:44 .gitconfig
-rw-r--r--   1 fab  staff   242B Sep  8  2013 .guard_history
drwxr-xr-x   3 fab  staff   102B Aug 18  2013 .heroku
-rw-r--r--   1 fab  staff   4.1K May 24 18:40 .irb-history
-rw-r--r--   1 fab  staff     0B Jan 20 18:36 .irbrc
-rw-------   1 fab  staff   211B Jan  1 19:51 .netrc
drwxr-xr-x  36 fab  staff   1.2K Sep 15  2013 .npm
-rw-r--r--   1 fab  staff   9.6K May 21 09:59 .pry_history
-rw-------   1 fab  staff   1.0K May 22 17:24 .rnd
drwxr-xr-x  29 fab  staff   986B Jan  2 18:40 .rvm
-rw-------   1 fab  staff   1.5K Feb 12 17:56 .sqlite_history
drwx------   5 fab  staff   170B Aug 18  2013 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x   6 fab  staff   204B Jun 22  2013 .subversion
-rw-------   1 root          staff   2.9K May  7 18:10 .viminfo
drwxr-xr-x   3 fab  staff   102B Sep 15  2013 .wireshark
drwxr-xr-x   7 fab  staff   238B Sep 15  2013 .wireshark-etc
-rw-r--r--   1 fab  staff   118B Jun 22  2013 .zprofile
-rw-r--r--   1 fab  staff    59B Jun 22  2013 .zshrc
drwxr-xr-x   3 fab  staff   102B May 22 13:45 Applications
drwx------+ 26 fab  staff   884B May 24 18:33 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x   5 fab  staff   170B May 24 18:35 Development
drwx------+  5 fab  staff   170B May 24 18:33 Documents
drwx------+  4 fab  staff   136B May 24 18:33 Downloads
drwx------@ 15 fab  staff   510B May 24 17:55 Dropbox
drwx------@ 54 fab  staff   1.8K May 22 12:51 Library
drwx------+  3 fab  staff   102B Jun 21  2013 Movies
drwx------+  5 fab  staff   170B Jun 27  2013 Music
drwx------+  6 fab  staff   204B Jul 26  2013 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  4 fab  staff   136B Jun 21  2013 Public
drwxr-xr-x  15 fab  staff   510B May 22 13:58 Qt
drwxr-xr-x   5 fab  staff   170B May 24 18:39 Sites
-rw-r--r--   1 fab  staff    44K May 22 19:53 config.log
drwxr-xr-x  10 root          admin   340B May 24 18:15 macports
```

**Can you make suggestions how I can clean up this mess of a root directory? Some of these files for example like `.zprofile` I feel like they don't belong and are just causing conflict or clutter.**

.zprofile contents:

> [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #
>   Load RVM into a shell session *as a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have some old (compiled) software in `/usr/local`, just get rid of it with:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local
```

then fix your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #1

if [ -f ~/.bash_git ]; then #2
  source ~/.bash_git
  export PS1='\033[00;37m\]\W\033[00;36m\]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\033[00m\]: '
fi

alias ll="ls -lahG" #3
```

and add to `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```